# Unfair closing of question

Tags: discussion

So, today I ask my first [question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/17700/identify-a-piece-in-the-air-intake-assembly?noredirect=1#comment26340_17700)
 in the mechanics site. I am completely clueless when it comes to mechanics and I thought I could find help there.

I had trouble identifying a part from my car that needs replacing; so i fire up google image search with the query: "civic 2004 air intake". I find a picture that shows the part i need, it has some watermark but whatever! i honestly didn't think it would affect the question being asked.

[image: this was the offending picture]

I have absolutely no connection to the site and the picture does show clearly the part that i need to identify. It was the first question I asked on the mechanics forum and it gets "deleted" because [Move more comments link to top](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/users/85/move-more-comments-link-to-top)
and [Paulster2](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/users/4152/paulster2) decided it was spam? without even giving me a chance to explain? I find that rude.

Is there a rule that forbids watermarks on attached pictures? (And even if there was why not suggest me to edit them out?) Am I required to actually open the trunk of my car and take a picture of the actual part?  If not then i'd like to kindly ask for the question to be reopened.

PD.: Thanks to [Zaid](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/users/675/zaid) for being kind enough to actually answer the question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question was flagged as spam, when I looked at it did look like it was an attempt to promote a website without disclosure. It looked like spam, you were a new user with no rep, there was no profile info, and this was your first post. So I deleted you question.

I am sorry you felt that we were rude to you, that was not the intent. We get quite a bit of spam posts and we try to delete them quickly. If you would have had some other questions, answers, rep, or would have affiliated your accounts (I am assuming since you posted to meta.stackexchange instead of meta.mechanics that you have other accounts) you question would not have been deleted as spam.

I have reopened the question. Welcome to the site!

Comment: Thanks for reopening the question (It was you?). I do have other accounts however it's a little bit weird that you have to create a new account for every stackexchange site. Apologies accepted! Spam makes it difficult for everyone doesnt it?

Comment: @dr_no Yes it was me that reopened it. They have made it really easy to make additional accounts, I think the reason they do is so you have the option to keep different sites separate, maybe you don't want you coworkers to know about your parenting problems on parenting for example.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it was more to do with how you posed the question - If you'd said something like "I'm trying to replace this part on my Civic and I don't know what it's called, here is an image I found on the internet to show what it is", or something similar, it probably wouldn't have been closed.

As it was, there was nothing in the question to indicate that you were not affiliated to the site the image came from - and unfortunately, sites like this attract quite a few people shamelessly plugging their own sites, and so the moderators have to be fairly ruthless to keep them out...

Conversely, editing the watermark out would have been just as bad, as then you get into copyright issues...

Comment: English is not my first language, so I usually prefer to keep things simple :)  that's why I kept the question simple. I have, however edited the question to be more in accord with your suggestions.

Comment: We have plenty of people here who don't have English as their first language (including, it would seem, quite a few from English-speaking countries!), so don't worry about the quality of your grammar etc - one of us will edit questions for clarity if they need it....

Answer (score 1):

I believe I was the original one to point out that this looked like spam. The entire reason I posted it as spam was *the answer to your question was in the title of the YouTube video* and the picture unceremoniously displayed the link to the parts vendor. This seemed obvious to me as spam. Replacement of this one of the first videos which showed up as a selection.

I too, am apologetic to have caused an issue with you. We are looking to broaden our user base and hope that new people will ask questions. Thanks for bringing it here to Meta for discussion and for resolution.

Comment: In hindsight, I can see how my question could've raised a few flags. But I'm thankful everything was sorted out and I got a helpful answer. Sorry for the necrocomment (is that even a thing? haha)

Comment: @dr_no - No worries about the comment. I'm glad you're still around and we were able to resolve. Just goes to show I'm not infallible, but I'm always hoping to learn from my mistakes. That you understood it was an honest mistake on my part is a great thing and much appreciated.